# Wordpress site not responding to background changes from media queries? Divi theme

Tags: css, wordpress, divi-theme

I'm working on my personal WordPress site, and when using media queries in the WordPress theme customizer, my site does not respond to the changes I've made to the background.

I am running the Divi theme, and used Chrome's inspect element to find which class I need to be changing.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .et_cover_background {
        background: url(https://echelon.enterprises/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/mobile-floor.jpg) repeat-y;
background-size:100vw;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769) {
    .et_cover_background {
        background: url(https://echelon.enterprises/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/echelon-enterprises.jpg) repeat-y;
    }
}
```

I expect the background of each page to change to "echelon-enterprises.jpg" on desktop, and to "mobile-floor.jpg" depending on the screen size. What am I doing wrong here? Am I just targeting the wrong class? I have also tried the "et-main-area" class, still not luck.

Comment: Your CSS looks fine, though we can't tell if your selectors are invalid without you listing the associated HTML. It's also possible that you simply need to clear your cache. Try `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge you should be able to see the HTML from the "view page source" right? [Here](https://echelon.enterprises) it is. I have tried clearing cache and opening in incognito (as I usually do when testing a site) but still no success.

Comment: (min-width: 769) should be (min-width: 769px)

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I have a hard time finding the css mentioned here on your actual website.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing px for the second declaration

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     body.et_cover_background {
         background: url(https://echelon.enterprises/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/mobile-floor.jpg) repeat-y;
         background-size:100vw;
    }
}
 @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
     body.et_cover_background {
         background: url(https://echelon.enterprises/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/echelon-enterprises.jpg) repeat-y;
    }
}
```